# How do i get a Report from jasperserver

Tags: java, swing, noclassdeffounderror, jasperserver

Having this code I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/EngineConfiguration
```

I am trying to get a report I have on the Jasper server. (not enough documentation regarding Jasper server).  How do I fix it?

```
    JServer server = new JServer();
    server.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/services/repository");
    server.setUsername("jasperadmin");
    server.setPassword("jasperadmin");
    WSClient client = new WSClient(server);

    ResourceDescriptor resourceDescriptor = new ResourceDescriptor();
    resourceDescriptor.setUriString ("/reports/samples/AllAccounts");
  Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   parameterMap.put("MY_PARAMETER_NAME", "myparametervalue");
    JasperPrint printer = client.runReport(resourceDescriptor, parameterMap);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(printer, false, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Add Apache axis jar to your run-time class path. It should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the error, it will be necessary to add the Jar containing the `EngineConfiguration` class to the run-time class-path of the app.

Searching for [`EngineConfiguration` at JarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.axis.EngineConfiguration) should give you a list of likely suspects.